# how to add a custom property with createUserwithEmailandPassword function in firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to create a new user account using `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`.
This account will be added for authentication and added to my `users` collection, and its `UID` will be the same and stored in a document.

Everything else works as intended, but for some reason, `displayName` is always set to `null` no matter what I have tried. `console.log(newUser.username)` return the correct username as I am typing in the `input`, so it has nothing to do with the event handler.

```
const [newUser, setNewUser] = React.useState(
        {
            email: "",
            username: "",
            password: "",
        })

const handleNewUserFormSubmit = (e) => {

        const { name, value } = e.target;

        setNewUser({
            ...newUser,
            [name]: value,
        })
    }
const createNewUser = () => {
        createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, newUser.email, newUser.password)
            .then((userCredential) => {
                // Signed in 

                console.log(newUser.username)

                const user = userCredential.user;
                const userRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);
                setDoc(userRef, {
                    displayName: newUser.username,
                    email: newUser.email,
                    profileURL: "",
                    userId: user.uid,
                    createdAt: Timestamp.fromDate(new Date()),
                })

                // ...
            }).then(() => {
                navigate("../channels")
            })
    }
```

The code for UI at below:

```
                    <Box className="primary-title">
                            <Typography variant="h5">
                                Create an account
                            </Typography>
                        </Box>
                        <Box className="input-position">
                            <Box className="form-group">
                                <FormHelperText className="input-placeholder">Email</FormHelperText>
                                <input className="form-style" type="email" name='email' onChange={e => handleNewUserFormSubmit(e)} style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }} />
                            </Box>
                            <Box className="form-group">
                                <FormHelperText className="input-placeholder">username</FormHelperText>
                                <input className="form-style" type="text" name='username' onChange={e => handleNewUserFormSubmit(e)} style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}
                                />
                            </Box>
                            <Box className="form-group">
                                <FormHelperText id="outlined-weight-helper-text" className="input-placeholder">Password</FormHelperText>
                                <input className="form-style" type="password" name="password" onChange={e => handleNewUserFormSubmit(e)}
                                    style={{ marginBottom: "20px" }}
                                />
                            </Box>
                        </Box>
                        <Box className="btn-position">
                            <Button className="btn" onClick={createNewUser}>Continue</Button>
                        </Box>
                        <Box component="span" className="register-container"><Link to="/" className="link">Already have an account?</Link></Box>
```

Answer (score 0):

When authenticating a user in Firebase with an email and password, a new Firebase user object is created. This means that a new account in Firebase Authentication is created. As you can see in the docs, such an object contains multiple fields, however, not all fields will contain a value. In case of authentication with email and pass, only two fields will be populated, the UID and the email. The `displayName` and `photoUrl` fields, for example, will remain uninitialized, hence that `null` that you were talking about.

If you want to avoid such cases, then besides the email and password text forms, you should also consider adding an additional one for the name for example, and then update the Firebase user object accordingly.

If you want, for example, to implement Firebase sign-in with Google, the Firebase user object will already have the `displayName` and `photoUrl` fields prepopulated with data from the Google account.

Comment: Do you mean that because certain properties like displayName and photoURL are already populated during user initialization, in order to add my custom property to a user, I have to add another function to update that user's document after ```createUserWithEmailandPassword()```?

Comment: No, certain properties like displayName and photoURL are left uninitialized while calling `createUserWithEmailAndPassword()`. You can do that at the same time you create the user with email and password, you can do it later. It's up to you to decide when you do that.

Comment: ```displayName: newUser.username``` this is the part where after I call ```createUserWithEmailAndPassword()```, I call ```setDoc()``` to set ```displayName``` to ```newUser.username``` which is the user input for username when they resgister. However, by checking the database, ```displayName``` is still set to ```null```

Comment: Once you get the user input, you have to update the document in Firestore. That operation isn't performed automatically. You have to do it explicitly.

Comment: Hey AnthonyDev220. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: It is helpful and informative, but it doesn't resolve my issue. I understand everything you said. I did update or set the doc explicitly. If you look at my posted code, in the ```setDoc()```, I update the ```displayName``` to ```newUser.username``` which the user input I get from ```useState()```, but it does not update my database. ```displayName``` is still set to ```null```. I have tried to use the ```updateDoc()``` function, that does not work etiher. I guess the problem lies on other part of my code.

Comment: It's hard to help with "does not work either", without providing more information.